# should I use release:prepare before release:perform?

Tags: maven

My regular CI build takes 1 hr and a release build takes 2 hrs. Can I skip the release:prepare and directly do a release:perform to save time? What will I miss?
Any other way to decrease the release build time if I cant skip this?

Thanks

Nube to mvn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is no you can't skip the release:prepare goal. If you want more then read on.

From the maven release plugin [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/prepare-mojo.html):

> Prepare for a release in SCM. Steps through several phases to ensure the POM is ready to be released and then prepares SCM to eventually contain a tagged version of the release and a record in the local copy of the parameters used.

What this actually does is the following:

1. Modify all your x-SNAPSHOT versions to simply x. So *1.0-snapshot* will turn into *1.0*
2. Build everything to make sure this still compiles and tests after the version change
3. Commit the changes (And tag them in your SCM)
4. Upgrade all the versions to the next *SNAPSHOT* version, in our case *1.1-SNAPSHOT*
5. Commit this new change

An intended by-product of this process are files with the poms to be built for the *release:perform* goal, so that's why you can't skip the *release:prepare*.

If you're still interested in shortening your build time, and do not care for all the commits to SCM you can implement your own release mechanism (which I do not recommend) using *maven-versions-plugin* and *maven-deploy-plugin*. See [this](https://axelfontaine.com/blog/final-nail.html) for details.